# VSCode won't find dotnet while normal cmd will on Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-code

I installed .NET SDK 5.0 and it seems to work in a cmd/PowerShell terminal fine, but VSCode won't find it even after a full restart of VSCode and the program that opened it. I can't use OmniSharp or anything else using `dotnet` while it's doing this. i'm on Windows 10 build 19042. [image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by clicking the File menu in VSCode and pressing the "Exit" option. I suppose this allowed it to find the updated PATH variable somehow.